# Popular performance meter program on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, monitoring

I am looking for a performance meter for Windows 7. Below is my list. I would like to hear from community to see what's more popular. My requirements are basically all System Explorer's pros + network monitoring.

- System Explorer 1.5:

  pros:

  1. A CPU usage bar on taskbar icon area.
  2. A performance graph including CPU/MEM/Swap/Pages faulted/IO reads writes, also shows the process name uses the most resources. So it's easy to check what's consuming CPU power and slowing down the whole system.
  3. In processes list, typing partial process name can filter out and narrow down to find a certain process.
  4. Nice aggregate meter view:
     [image]

  cons:

  1. No network info
- Resource Monitor

  pros:

  1. Same as System Explorer #2, plus network info.
  2. Nice meter view.

  cons:

  1. No CPU usage bar on taskbar.
- Rainmeter
- Sysinternals Process Explorer

  cons:

  1. This one is kinda heavy-duty, good for debugging, not for monitoring IMO.
- Google Desktop Search gadget: system monitor

Comment: This would be more suitable for the [Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com) than as a Q&A.

Comment: @Sathya, if that's the case, how can I post on Super User blog? Or can you please do that for me?

Comment: please refer to [this](http://blog.superuser.com/contribute/) or drop by [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/356/super-user-blog-editor-room)

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is a CPU monitor on the taskbar with resource monitor, just run resource monitor, then run task manager and minimize it.